# Google Apps Script: How to store data on google cloud storage?

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to store google documents on google cloud storage. I am a admin user and have access for google cloud storage.
I using this code:

```
 function myFunction() {

   var base="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control"
  var fetchArgs=googleOAuth_('provisioning',base)
  fetchArgs.payload=<content_data_that you want to put on GCS>
  fetchArgs.method='PUT'
  fetchArgs. contentType=<content_type>
  fetchArgs.host="<bucket_name>.storage.googleapis.com"
  var url='https://storage.googleapis.com/<bucket_name>/<file_name>' 
  var result=UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,fetchArgs)
    }

function googleOAuth_(name,scope) {
  var oAuthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService(name);
  oAuthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope="+scope);
  oAuthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken");
  oAuthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");
    oAuthConfig.setConsumerKey(consumerKey);
  oAuthConfig.setConsumerSecret(consumerSecret);
  return {oAuthServiceName:name, oAuthUseToken:"always"};
}
```

When I run this code, it gives 503 server error.
Any suggestion would be helpful to me.

This problem has been solved. Updated the code with correction.

Comment: Did you set your Key and Secret?

Comment: yes....i set all required things....

Answer (score 1):

I was also trying to use the Google Cloud Storage API from Google Apps Script. I found the following library:

https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2

The documentation there was actually even more helpful because it showed me how I didn't need the library at all:

> Even if your API is not covered by either, you can still use Apps Script to obtain the OAuth2 token for you. Simply edit the script's manifest to include the additional scopes that your API requires. When the user authorizes your script they will also be asked to approve those additional scopes. Then use the method ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() in your code to access the OAuth2 access token the script has acquired and pass it in the Authorization header of a UrlFetchApp.fetch() call.
>
> Visit the sample [NoLibrary](https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2/tree/master/samples/NoLibrary) to see an example of how this can be done.

The key takeaways for me (and posterity):

1. Make `appsscript.json` visible and add `oauthScopes` with all the [API scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#storage) desired plus `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request`.
2. Set `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` second param to `headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}`
3. Ignore the `&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]` seen in Google API examples.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Cloud Storage docs mention that if you use OAuth 1.0 you also need to pass the API key.

https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/authorizing

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it but it looks like it might simplify you life:

> OAuthService
>
> by James Ferreira - GoogleScriptExamples.com
>
> This Library takes the work out of using OAuth. It has one method
>   getAuth(' ', optUserScope) and works with all of the
>   Google APIs. See example here.
>
> Project Key: MM5uQxqjwkMiuJW2zE50SgUF7jOZt2NQ8

See:
https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/custom-methods/google-oauth